# How do you check if data already exist of that id with discord.js mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-modules, discord.js

So I try to insert data into my table with MySQL package for nodejs and as you can see the content from the link I made an if statement that the row of the select query is empty do this query to add data or if the data already exist just send a return message. My problem is that its not reading the if statement properly, saying that no rows exist while there is existing data.

error:

> code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
>     errno: 1062,
>     sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'",
>     sqlState: '23000',
>     index: 0,
>     sql: "INSERT INTO test (discord_id, empire_name) VALUES ('188320189866180617', 'empire')"

code:

```
const db = require('../../db');

module.exports = {
    name: "start",
    category: "empire",
    description: "Start your journey to create your empire.",
    usage: "<string>",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        if (message.deletable) message.delete();

        // No args
        if (!args[0]) {
            return message.reply("please give your empire a name.")
                .then(m => m.delete(5000));
        }

        db.query(`SELECT * FROM test WHERE discord_id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => { 
            if(err) throw err;

            if(!rows.length) {  
                db.query(`INSERT INTO test (discord_id, empire_name) VALUES ('${message.author.id}', '${args[0]}')`);

                return message.channel.send(`${args[0]} has been established!`);
            } else {  
                return message.channel.send(`You've already started an empire.`);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Handle callback for db.query(`INSERT INTO test......`) because this is an async operation.

Comment: Thnx man I dont get the duplicate error anymore but it still using the query because it still says the rows are empty but it should be not bcs the first time you use the command it inserts data if the select result is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was big dumdum. I was using phpmyadmin and xampp, not the mysql server one. All queries are now working properly but thnxs for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This will always in case of parallel execution of API.

```
    const db = require('../../db');

    module.exports = {
        name: "start",
        category: "empire",
        description: "Start your journey to create your empire.",
        usage: "<string>",
        run: async (client, message, args) => {

            if (message.deletable) message.delete();

            // No args
            if (!args[0]) {
                return message.reply("please give your empire a name.")
                    .then(m => m.delete(5000));
            }
            let sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO test (discord_id, empire_name) 
                SELECT * FROM (SELECT '${message.author.id}', '${args[0]}') AS tmp
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT * FROM test WHERE discord_id = '${message.author.id}'
                ) LIMIT 1`;
            db.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => { 
                if(err) throw err;

                if (result && result.affectedRows == 0) {
                    return message.channel.send(`You've already started an empire.`);
                } else {
                    return message.channel.send(`${args[0]} has been established!`);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It threw the duplicate entry again:

code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
  errno: 1062,
  sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'",
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO test (discord_id, empire_name) \n' +
    "            SELECT * FROM (SELECT '188320189866180617', 'yeet') AS tmp\n" +
    '            WHERE NOT EXISTS (\n' +
    "                SELECT * FROM test WHERE discord_id = '188320189866180617'\n" +
    '            ) LIMIT 1 and again Im very thankful of the reply.

Comment: Share the table schema